# Passing interfaces into functions

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to write a configuration package that takes a json filename and a configuration struct. It should unmarshal the json into the passed-in struct and return it. **I'm trying to work with interfaces so I can pass any struct I want**

The error is:

`panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not *main.ConfigurationData`

I'm not quite sure how to solve this issue.

Here is my main package

```
package main

import (
    "config"
    "commons"
)

type ConfigurationData struct {
    S3ARN string `json:"S3ARN"`
    SQSQueueUrl string `json:"SQSQueueUrl"`
}

var configData *ConfigurationData

func main(){
    configData=config.Load("aws.config.json",configData).(*ConfigurationData)
    commons.Dump(configData)
}
```

Here is my config package

```
package config

import (
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
    "sync"
    "commons"
)

var configLock = new(sync.RWMutex)

func Load(filename string,config interface{})interface{} {
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    commons.CheckErrorf(err, "Config Open Error")
    defer file.Close()
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
    configLock.Lock()
    err = decoder.Decode(&config)
    commons.CheckErrorf(err, "Config Decode Error")
    configLock.Unlock()
    return config
}
```

Comment: Please provide the json dummy file in your case to regenerate the issue.

Comment: Why are you modifying the struct _and_ returning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51887678/2160958) explains well why you get the exception.

What you should do:

When the **encoding/json** package runs into a type that implements the **Marshaler** interface, it uses that type’s `MarshalJSON()` method instead of the default marshaling code to turn the object into JSON. Similarly, when decoding a JSON object it will test to see if the object implements the **Unmarshaler** interface, and if so it will use the `UnmarshalJSON()` method instead of the default unmarshaling behavior.

Mine solution for this would be to implement **UnmarshalJSON** method on `*ConfigurationData` and method `Load` should accept [**Unmarshaler**](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface instead of `interface{}`.

You can read more about technics here: https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/advanced-encoding-decoding/

Then you simple would do `json.Unmarshal(b, &config)` inside the `Load` method where **b** is `[]byte` read from file.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, their code is not "correct", and _your_ solution *is*. Sorry! :-) (upvoted)

Comment: @zerkms yeah.  If you were the one that posted to goplayground, the playground example works because all files opened on goplayground behave as though they're empty.  So, no data is read by the decoder, and since it was passed an interface pointer, a null value is assigned to it.  A null pointer satisfies the type assertion and it works there.

Comment: can you provide a code sample? Im having difficulty implementing this.

Comment: @ctt yep, I initially thought it's a compile time error

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation on json.Unmarshall](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) unmarshalling into an interface value will unmarshall to a new struct of one of a predefined list of types:

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of
>   these in the interface value:
>
> ```
> bool, for JSON booleans 
> float64, for JSON numbers
> string, for JSON
> strings []interface{}, for JSON arrays 
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> nil for JSON null
> ```

In your case, the type that was chosen was `map[string]interface{}`.  Within your function, a pointer to that newly unmarshalled struct is stored in the config parameter and returned.  The panic occurs as the type of the value returned is not the type you're asserting it is.

Comment: OK then how do i convert the map to a configuration struct after returning the interface?

Comment: By writing a copy constructor (in go, a plain old function) that copies the data from the struct into a new ConfigurationData struct.  Or you can try @Vardius's solution and try to define an interface to an Unmarshaller that configuration struct definers can create.  It's a puts a little more work on whoever defines custom config types, but with that approach, within Unmarshallers that satisfy the interface, you can pass Decode() a pointer with a concrete type, and have json.Unmarshall do the unpacking for you.